# How to update activity's layout after resume from other activity ?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've implemented a timetable and i'd like to know how to update the timetable activity (the layout of this activity) after adding an event from seperate activity.
To be more specific , there is "add event" button in the timetable layout and then new activity is opened and then i want to come back to the timetable layout and show the new event.

Where do i write the code that updates the timetable layout ? 
Thanks...

Comment: From where is your timetable data loaded into the first Activity? My suggestion would be to load/reload that data in `onStart()`, or to use something that reloads by itself (e.g. with a `ContentObserver` if you are using something with `Uri`s)

Comment: I create the timetable in onCreate method

Comment: Try looking at the `startActivityForResult(...)` and `onActivityResult(...)` methods of the `Activity` class. If you've designed the app correctly there is always a possibility the user decides they don't want to add an event after all and they click Cancel to return to the first `Activity`. If the result returned from the second `Activity` indicates a new event has been added then update things in the `onActivityResult(...)` method. If the result shows the user has cancelled then don't do anything in `onActivityResult(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onResume` method of your timetable activity.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    //your update code here
}
```

> [The onResume method is] called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.

Comment: So the solution is to build the layout again like in onCreate,  or i can edit the only views that has been changed(and need to be colored) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right. Your layout should still be existing at this point, so you can just edit it.

Comment: Ok. So,  if  i implement the changes  in onResume it will  be shown with the current updates?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, what you mean.